# Update GitLab installation after upgrading the box

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to update my gitlab installation. So I simply follows that documentation :

```
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/patch_versions.md
```

However, when executing the following command I get that error :

```
$ bundle exec rake "gitlab:workhorse:install[/home/git/gitlab-workhorse]" RAILS_ENV=production  --trace
** Invoke gitlab:workhorse:install (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute gitlab:workhorse:install
rake aborted!
Gitlab::TaskFailedError: Gitlab::TaskFailedError
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/task_helpers.rb:87:in `run_command!'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/workhorse.rake:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/workhorse.rake:18:in `chdir'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/workhorse.rake:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:workhorse:install
```

I'd like to give some context. I just updated my box so packages are up-to-date but I don't know what the implication with Gitlab.

Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: You have a source install of GitLab? What version were you upgrading from and to?

Comment: well, I did a reinstall following the docs.

Comment: When you originally did the install, did you follow https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md? This would be the first document to follow for an install/reinstall. The document you linked to would be for small/patch release upgrades from an existing install.

Comment: hmm...I fix it doing a fresh install.